# Backbone.js - rendering collection with jquery mobile renders without styling

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm creating a mobile view that uses backkbone.js and jquery mobile.

I have a collection that I render to the page, styled up to use jquery mobile's [listview](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/index.html). The collection loads and is rendered on the page with the correct html, but renders as an un-styled list, not how it should render in jquery mobile. If I then inspect the list, copy it as html, and paste it into my html page as static html, that html displays correctly!

What am I doing wrong? This is my first foray into both backbone.js and jquery mobile so it could be something simple.

*Code:*

My templates:

```
<script id="change-template" type="text/template">
<a href="#">{{ Description }}</a>
<p>{{ ChannelLabel }}</p>
</script>

<script id="changes-template" type="text/template">
<ul id="changes-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true"></ul>
</script>
```

My views:

```
window.ChangeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.template = _.template($('#change-template').html());
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
})

window.ChangesView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName : "div",

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.template = _.template($('#changes-template').html());
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);
    },

    render: function () {

        var collection = this.collection;

        // Render the template
        $(this.el).html(this.template({}));

        // Then get a handle to the element inside the template.
        var $changes = this.$('#changes-list');

        this.collection.each(function(change) {
            var view = new ChangeView({model: change, collection: collection});
            $changes.append(view.render().el);
        })

        return this;
    }
});
```

Example HTML output:

```
<div id="changes" data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
<ul id="changes-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true"><li>
  <a href="#">Link Up</a>
  <p>GF1A-R2P24 - 23</p>
  </li><li>
  <a href="#">Link Down</a>
  <p>GF1A-R2P24 - 23</p>
  </li></ul>
</div>
```

This is how I load the page:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function () {

    window.changes = new Changes();
    var view = new ChangesView({ collection: changes, el:"#changes" });
    changes.fetch();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so by looking around, I found that adding this solved the issue:

```
$(this.el).trigger( "pagecreate" );
```

But this feels wrong - why should I need to trigger that event myself?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118017/list-view-css-not-rendering-jquery-mobile#comment14589163_11118017. Where did you add this code ?

Comment: Dear Matt, I am also having the same problem. Could you please give me the line number or place where you have inserted this piece to make it work.

Comment: I added that at the bottom of the render method for the view - HTH

Comment: Worked for me- thanks! Is there a way to make this more automatic? For example, binding a function with jQuery whenever a backbone render is triggered? It's fairly arbitrary and easy to forget putting this line into every render() method

Answer (score 1):

If all the DOM-changes were done before the jQuery Mobile started styling the page, it would work just fine. However, Backbone.js' events cause parts of the page to re-render asynchronously, leaving parts of the page unstyled.

Calling .trigger("pagecreate") or "create" triggers jQuery Mobile to restyle the page/elements.

(Each time jQuery Mobile displays a page it reads the data- attributes and applies the appropriate styling.)

This is necessary because jQuery Mobile and Backbone.js are separate frameworks.