# List view css not rendering jquery mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, cordova, backbone.js

I am making an application using jquery mobile, phone gap and backbone.js. In this I am dynamically creating pages and appending it to the body element of the html page. I am also dynamically creating a list view for a particular page. However the list view just shows plain links for the li tags. The code for my view is below

```
directory.views.UserListPage = Backbone.View.extend({

 initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template(directory.utils.templateLoader.get('user-list-page'));
},

 events:{ "click .add-button": "addButton_clicked"
},
render: function(eventName) {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.listView = new directory.views.UserListView({el: $('ul', this.el),model: this.model});
    this.listView.render();

    $content = $(this.el).children(":jqmData(role=content)");
  $(this.el).appendTo($("body")).page();

    $content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)" ).listview();
    return this;
},

addButton_clicked: function(event) {
console.log("clicked");
    event.preventDefault();
   directory.app.navigate("addUser", {trigger: true});
}});

directory.views.UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({


initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
},

render: function(eventName) {
    $(this.el).empty();
    _.each(this.model.models, function(user) {
        $(this.el).append(new directory.views.UserListItemView({model: user}).render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}});

directory.views.UserListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

tagName: "li",

events:
{
"click" : "borrowHistory"
}
,
initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template(directory.utils.templateLoader.get('user-list-item'));
},

render: function(eventName) {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
} ,
borrowHistory: function(event) {



    var children = $(event.currentTarget).children();
    var attribute = children[0].dataset.id;
   var url = "#/rs/" + attribute +  "/borrowHistory";

   directory.app.navigate(url, {trigger: true});
   return false;
}});
```

My template looks like this

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
    <a href="#addUser" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" >Add</a>
    <h1>Borrow Mate</h1>

  </div>
  <div id="listUser" data-role="content"  >
  <div id="listcontent">
     <ul  id="userList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="e" data-divider-theme="e" data-count-theme="e"> </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

User list item

```
<div class="userListItem" data-id = "<%= id %>" >
    <b><%= Name %></b>
    <span class="ui-li-count"><%= Credits %></span>
</div>
```

[image: Added a screenshot of my output]

Comment: Does $content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)" ).listview('refresh'); work?

Comment: no the same problem. I dont get it because the header is styled fine. I can also see the border of the list view but the elements inside are not formatted.

Comment: Could you post `directory.views.UserListView` code?

Comment: i updated the code with UserListView

Comment: ok, thanks. perhaps the problem is with the `UserListItemView` template. do you use the DOM inspector?

Comment: I cant view it on the web page only on the phone in the application. I have uploaded the listitemview template also.

Comment: ok, but i don't see the template. i mean, `user-list-item`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12831/discussion-between-vbk-and-user1248256)

Comment: I manager to get a debugging tool. No styles are rendered for the li tag. The ul tag gets the style correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to refresh the listview

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html

So After you append the list items you need to refresh, like this

```
$('#userList').listview('refresh');
```

Using the id attribute of the template you have provided

```
<ul id="userList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="e" data-divider-theme="e" data-count-theme="e">
</ul>
```

Comment: where do i add that in ?? after I append the page to the body ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call the refresh method on the listview in the pageshow event, or if it's the first time it's being created you may need to call the create method.

For example

```
$(document).delegate('#yourPage', 'pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        $('#userList').listview('refresh');
          //or surround in a try catch block
       /* try {
           $('#userList').listview();
          } catch {
           $('#userList').listview('refresh');
         }*/
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure render() is called before you 'navigate' to your page.

This way jQuery Mobile has time to mark-up your content before it is displayed.

I got around this issue by delegating the render and navigation events with pub/sub, so they get called at the right time (after the data arrives), this eliminates the race condition issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If style is not applying for particularly li elements .Check the class associated to li. Make that too refresh.

check out in below format

$(#userList .userListItem).listview("refresh");